# Access CakePHP controller or request object outside mvc

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is there any way to access the current controller or request object outside mvc in CakePHP(2.*)?

Basically I need to access the request object in a library that is designed for CakePHP but should function on its own as much as possible - in other words I'd like to avoid any unnecessary lib-specific initialization code in the controller itself to keep the.

I have written a component for this purpose but not all calls to the lib will be directly from the controller. I'd also like to avoid passing the $controller or $request variable around anywhere else but inside the lib.

I've never looked into CakePHP class loading much, but I can recall something about ClassRegistry from when CakePHP 1.3 was new. Soon after testing ClassRegistry in a controller action I found it to be empty(*determined with ClassRegistry::keys() and pr()'ing directly from the class*)

So, is there any friendly way to get the request object or should I resort to uglier methods?

Comment: Do you thought about Vendors? I talk from Cakephp 1.2.x background? If you mean that you want to run or access another controller from the current controller it will be done too.

Comment: I mean that I'd like to know if CakePHP has a way to get the current controller from anywhere in the app - mainly from Library type classes that have no relation to the MVC structure of CakePHP.

I've kind of found a way to go around this problem but I'm still curious, so I'll leave the question open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Router::getRequest()` should get you the CakeRequest instance.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following code example help you?

```
//in Socials Controller importing SocialUsers controller
function __checkSocialUser($title, $user_id){
    App::import('Controller', 'SocialUsers');
        $SocialUsers = new SocialUsersController;
        $SocialUsers->constructClasses();
        $ourUserId = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $SocialUsers->data = array('SocialUser' => array('title' => $title, 'identifier' => $user_id, 'user_id' => $ourUserId));
        $result = $SocialUsers->checkUser($title, $user_id);....
```

Comment: I'm sorry, no. I need to access the controller that is currently executing either through the client/browser request or requestAction().

Comment: Well, you could able to access controller's action through JSON. Just make your action output apply JSON i.e set the $this->autorender = false and adjust echo or printf to printout JSON text format.